# Chess clock android app

Tags: software, android

I play chess using my board with friends from time to time. I don't have a clock.
Since I don't play chess that much with friends, I'd rather not to buy a clock, I mostly play online.

Lucky me I found some [android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Hefestus.ChessClock.Free&hl=en) that does the trick, I install it, put the phone between me and my opponent, I do the move and press a button, he does another button from his part.

All is great, until some dude decided to call me :) the clock reset, I had to set it again. The same dude decides to knock on my door and there was no way to pause the clock!

My requirements are:

- Android chess clock app that you can pause, and that pauses itself when someone calls you.

Comment: if you find this question to be off topic, please migrate it to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com, otherwise you can delete my comment

Comment: I would put the phone in airplane mode so I won't be getting any calls. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [chess.com Chess Clock app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chess.clock) has a big pause button right smack dab in the middle of the screen *and* pauses itself when someone calls. (Just tested it to verify)

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but this app has a pause button and will also pause if you answer a call:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kokajin.applications.chessclock